# React Native app crashes on save when dayjs is used

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dayjs

I'm having this rather strange issue where dayjs completely crashes my app when I save.
The changes to my app don't propagate to the simulator, instead Hermes instantly crashes, citing the crash happens in whichever module I last saved.

If I instead manually reload the app (pressing r in the debug output), the app loads again correctly. Saving crashes it.

If I instead remove all mentions of dayjs from that file and hit save, things then render correctly, even if dayjs was used in a different component.

It's almost as if the issue is somehow caused by Watchman.

Here's an example of some code causing the crash:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import {Text} from '@ui-kitten/components';

// other imports omitted

const DashboardScreen = () => {
  return (
    <DefaultLayout containerStyle={localStyles.containerStyle}>
      <Text style={localStyles.title} category="h6">
        {dayjs().format('MMMM, YYYY')}
      </Text>
    </DefaultLayout>
  );
};
```

Where `Text` is from UIKitten.

It then throws me the following error 7 times:

```
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object

This error is located at:
    in DownloadBtn (created by ReportDownload)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ReportDownload)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ReportDownload)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by TouchableOpacity)
    in TouchableOpacity (created by TouchableOpacity)
    in TouchableOpacity (created by TouchableWithoutFeedback)
    in TouchableWithoutFeedback (created by TouchableWeb)
    in TouchableWeb (created by Card)
    in Card
    in Wrapper (created by Card)
    in WrappingElement (created by WidgetCard)
    in WidgetCard (created by ReportDownload)
    in ReportDownload (created by DashboardScreen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Layout)
    in Layout
    in Wrapper (created by Layout)
    in WrappingElement (created by DefaultLayout)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DefaultLayout)
    in RCTScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)
    in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by DefaultLayout)
    in TouchableWithoutFeedback (created by DefaultLayout)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by KeyboardAvoidingView)
    in KeyboardAvoidingView (created by DefaultLayout)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DefaultLayout)
    in DefaultLayout (created by DashboardScreen)
    in DashboardScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by SetupStackScreen)
    in SetupStackScreen (created by RootRouter)
    in RootRouter (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in Suspense (created by App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ModalPanel)
    in ModalPanel (created by ApplicationProvider)
    in ThemeProvider (created by StyleProvider)
    in MappingProvider (created by StyleProvider)
    in StyleProvider (created by ApplicationProvider)
    in ApplicationProvider (created by App)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by RootApp)
    in ReactNativeProfiler (created by RootApp)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by __Sentry.TouchEventBoundary)
    in __Sentry.TouchEventBoundary (created by RootApp)
    in RootApp
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in MyApp(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

With the following view in the simulator:

[image: iphone simulator screenshot]

The line number for DashboardScreen in the image matches the line number of dayjs in the componeent.

Anyone got an idea why this might be happening?

I'm currently running React Native 0.70.8 and dayjs 1.11.7.
Additionally, this is **not** an Expo app.

Comment: you should rather check the logs in `logcat`, not in RN console

Comment: how does your import of dayjs looks like?

Comment: @JelteHomminga `import dayjs from 'dayjs';`

Comment: @injecteer isn't that an android tool? I'm doing ios development

Comment: By way of another data point - I'm able to get a similar behaviour with a stock expo app using your code snippet, if I introduce _any_ error in the file, save, reload within the debugger, then save the corrected file. That seems like `watchman` can get befuddled, although there is [a similar (but not identical) open issue on the dayjs GitHub](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/2003).

Comment: I wonder if it could be due to Prettier

Comment: I just noticed that you're using the `advancedFormat` plug-in .... Any other `dayjs` plugins/locales/non-standard config in use?

Comment: @motto yes I use utc in a different file. How can you tell I'm using `advancedFormat`? isn't `format` part of the core? Also I wasn't totally sure where to put my plugins, so I threw them all into the app root; but I seem to remember it crashing even when I didn't do that.

Comment: `advancedFormat` shows up in that error stack trace. Didn't dig particularly deeply into the mechanics of the plugins but they're monkey patching the `dayjs` instance (which is shared between all modules in the app). Could be sensitive to invocation order or locale or such.

Comment: Even without `advancedFormat` it still crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253231/discussion-between-motto-and-electric-coffee).